# Capistrano 3.x capture output line by line

Tags: ruby, capistrano

In Capistrano 2.x you could capture the output line by line using

```
run "ls -la" do |channel, stream, data|
    puts data
end
```

This does not work in Capistrano 3.x, and the `capture` and `execute` commands do not seem to provide the same functionality.

Is there a way to replicate the 2.x behaviour in 3.x?

Comment: did you have a look at the `stream` method? http://rdoc.info/github/capistrano/capistrano/Capistrano/Configuration/Actions/Inspect#stream-instance_method

Comment: That seems to be a Capistrano 2.x method, it's not available on 3.x https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/search?q=stream&ref=cmdform&type=Code . In 3.x it uses the sshkit methods as far as I can tell https://github.com/leehambley/sshkit/search?q=capture&type=Code

Comment: oh yeah, that's true. capistrano 3 is not "official" i guess

Comment: Huh, didn't know that. Just did a gem upgrade and it upgraded to 3.

Comment: well, i am not sure, just read something about the maintainer is going to retire blabla not releasing the new version bla bla.

Comment: [The maintainer clearly had been suffering from overwork. It sounded like he didn't want to support Capistrano 2.x but has now confirmed it is supported.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/capistrano) Clearly, it will take a few days before conclusions are drawn, but Capistrano has a lot of support.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
output = capture('cat ~/file.cnf')
output.each_line do |line|
    puts line
end
```

Thats how I read lines using capture. If you want to capture something specific on a line you can use

```
if line.include? 'user'
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't have quite the same behaviour as 2.x's method. `capture` waits for the command to finish before returning the output instead of streaming it back line by line as `run` did.

Answer (score 3):

I could not figure out how to get *streaming* output in cap 4 either. For me in Cap 3.4.0 with sshkit 1.11.1, `execute` was not doing it.

But looking at the sshkit docs, here's one way to hack it, which kind of works:

```
class StreamOutputInteractionHandler
  def on_data(_command, stream_name, data, channel)
    $stderr.print data
  end
end

# ...

execute :whatever, interaction_handler: StreamOutputInteractionHandler.new
```

It might do weird things, especially if you are executing on multiple hosts, it will of course interleave the output.  You can use capistrano log similar to the way the built in MappingInteractionHandler does, but I wanted to print directly to console so I could get partial output before newlines (a progress bar from a rake task).

Discussion with sshkit maintainer here. https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/issues/395#issuecomment-288489866

Answer (score -4):

It's actual way simpler in Capistrano 3.x, you can just do:

```
execute "ls -a"
```

And the output will be streamed automatically, it's great for streaming log files etc.

Comment: It would be great if you could clarify what the problem you encountered was, I'm using this on 4 different Rails apps across ~30 hosts without any problems. So if there is a potential issue, it would be useful to know! E.g. I use this http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2013/12/tailing-log-files-with-capistrano-3/ to tail log files

Comment: execute "whatever" doesn't stream the output anywhere

Comment: Any chance you could link me to the code you're using. I tested it with an empty app here yesterday after I saw your post (both for individual commands and tail -f etc) and it streams as expected. `execute` is actually handled by SSHKit and this is exactly how it is supposed to behave.

Comment: Doesn't work that way for me in capistrano 3.4.0 either, I'm getting no output to console at all with `execute`. Hmm. But I'd really like to get streaming output.